# Induction: $(2a-1)^{n}-1$ is an even number

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Just wanted to ask whether there are any mistakes.

**Proof by induction:**

> $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: (2a-1)^{n}-1 , a \in \mathbb{N}, $ is an even number.

**Base case:**

$n=1: (2a-1)^{1}-1 = 2a-1-1 = 2a-2 = 2\cdot(a-1) \rightarrow$ even number

**Inductive hypothesis:**

Assume that $(2a-1)^{n}-1$ is an even number. So we can say $(2a-1)^{n}-1 = 2k$, for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Inductive step:**

$n \rightarrow n+1$, so we have to show $(2a-1)^{n+1}-1 = 2k$

$(2a-1)^{n+1}-1\\ =  (2a-1)^{n}\cdot(2a-1)-1 \\= (2a-1)^{n}\cdot(2a-1)-(2a-1)+(2a-1)-1 \\= (2a-1)\cdot[(2a-1)^{n} -1]+(2a-1)-1 \\=(2a-1)\cdot 2k+2a-2 \\ =2\cdot[(2a-1)\cdot k+a-1]$

$\Longrightarrow$ for $n+1$ is an even number

Comment: It looks correct, but why would anyone try to prove this statement by induction?

Comment: Be careful, you need $(2a-1)^{n+1}-1=2K$ for some $K.$ This is important because you already have $(2a-1)^n-1=2k,$ so you want a different variable.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, will change that

Comment: A less epiphany demanding approach is to just immediately substitute $2k+1$ in for $(2a - 1)^n$ and then simplify that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I agree that anyone who is well versed in mathematics would avoid proving this statement by induction since it is made trivial by using tools of modular arithmetic ($(2a-1)^n-1 \equiv (0-1)^n - 1 \equiv 1-1\equiv 0$).  That said, the purpose of the exercise being assigned isn't necessarily to have the student prove that specific statement, but rather to acquaint them with the method of proof by induction with a simple enough example that they can focus their efforts on the method used rather than having to work so hard on the finer details and nuances that could have arisen.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think that it is a pedagogical disaster to ask students to prove by induction statements for which they do not feel the need for such a proof.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is equivalent to $$(2a-1)^n$$ is odd for all $n\in N$

Note that product of two odd integers is odd.

Now we start the induction.

It is true for $n=1$ because $2a-1$ is odd.

If true for $n$ then $$ (2a-1)^{n+1} = (2a-1)^n(2a-1)$$ is the product of two odd integers so it is odd.

Answer (score 1):

not sure why going this way, but it easier to show that $(2a-1)^n$ is always an odd number, also in induction (it's elementary, doesn't sure if it can be counted as induction), going something like that:

base: $n=1$ : for every $a\in \Bbb Z$, $2a-1$ is an odd number

induction hypothesis: for every $n'\le n \in \Bbb N$, $(2a-1)^{n'}$ is odd.

inductive step: we will show that $(2a-1)^{n+1}$ is an odd number: $$(2a-1)^{n+1}=(2a-1)(2a-1)^n$$ by hypothesis, both expressions are odd, and multiplication of odd number are odd. then for every $n\in \Bbb N$, $(2a-1)^n$ is odd and therfore $(2a-1)^n-1$ are even

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, as alternative in the induction step we can also use the induction hypotesis as follows

$$(2a-1)^{n+1}-1=(2a-1)\color{red}{(2a-1)^{n}}-1=(2a-1)\color{red}{(2k+1)}-1=2k(2a-1)+2a-2$$